# Reset $_POST values after submition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Basically, I'm trying to do is to reset all the form values after submission. I've tried every post but not got success. Please tell me the way of resetting values after submission so that after refreshing the page the form doesn't submit again. Thank you Here is my piece of code. I've tried headers but it is giving me errors so tell me another way of resetting the submit post after submission.

```
    <form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" role="form">
     <div class="form-group">
     <label>Name</label>
     <span class="Name_input">  </span> 
     <input name="Name" id="Name"  type="text"     class="form-control" required  placeholder="Your name" />

                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Email</label>
                                     <span class="Email_input">  </span> 
                                    <input name="Email" id="Email" type="text" class="form-control" required  placeholder="Email address" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Phone</label>
                                    <input name="Phone" id="Phone" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="Phone number" />          

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Subject</label>
                             <span class="Subject_input">  </span> 
                            <input name="Subject" id="Subject"  type="text" class="form-control" required  placeholder="Subject" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Message</label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Write you message here..."  style="height:100px;"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <input type="Submit" name="Submit" value="Send message"  class="btn btn-two"/><p><br /></p>
                    </form>


  if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
  {
  $User_Name=$_POST['Name'];    
  $User_Email=$_POST['Email'];
  if(isset($_POST['Phone']))
  $User_PhoneNumber=$_POST['Phone'];
  else
  $User_PhoneNumber="";
  $Feedback_Subject=$_POST['Subject'];
  $Feedback_Message=$_POST['message'];
  $Inserted=mysqli_query($con, "Insert into feedback (Name , Email, Phone_Number, Subject, Message ) 
  VALUES('" . $User_Name . "', '" .$User_Email . "', '" . $User_PhoneNumber. "', '" . $Feedback_Subject . "','" . $Feedback_Message . "')");
  }
```

Comment: reset the post values as `$_POST = array();` after submission, other solution is `header()`

Comment: After submitting the form once, it's not gonna submit itself again, that's not the default behavior. Under what circumstances you're facing this behavior?

Comment: @devpro where to write this $_POST = array(); in my code

Comment: after submission or process completion

Comment: @RajdeepPaul when /i referesh my page after submission than it submit the values again in db

Comment: @devpro I didn't get you like in my case where should I put that line. my code is in front of you

Comment: The best solution is NOT to submit to SELF, instead submit to another seperate script

Comment: @RiggsFolly  you want to say that I should make another php page on which I do submission

Comment: reset the values as empty right??

Comment: @devpro how can we do this by resetting fields values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form should not resubmit just because you refresh the page. However, I just using header(), to redirect to a fresh page, even if the same.

So, straight after the sql query:

```
header("Location: page.php");
```

and replace page with which ever page it is.

also, put

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
```

at the very top (before html) of your script to prevent `error: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent`

...and for your other question:

```
$(window).bind("pageshow", function() {
    $("#formvalue1,#formvalue2,#formvalue3").val('');

});
```

this will get triggered when the page is shown, even if not reloaded.

Comment: error: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent

Comment: not a problem... put ob_start() at the very beginning of script

Comment: Alternatively you can put entire PHP block at the beginning of the page, this way you won't need the ob_start()

Comment: @Caspar one question more when i press browser back button than the values which I enter should reset again how can I achieve that ???

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @ArturoO

Comment: That is not possible unless you go back twice maybe ... as header() refreshes the page.

Comment: sorry, I'm asking when I submit the form and header move me on another page like Success.php and then from Success.php button I press browsers back button  and get on the same page where I submit the form. I'm asking to reset the values which we write in the text fields did you get me ? @CasparWylie

Comment: that is a little more complicated. As the browser does this by default. Use javascript, see my updated answer